# Yup error this must be a `object` type, but the final value was: `null`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, yup

I have a validation schema defined using Yup as below

```
export const mySchema = {
    ['add-record']: yup.object().shape({
        'myId': yup
            .string()
            .nullable()
            .required()
    })
}
```

On click of some button, I invoke the validation as below;

```
await mySchema['add-record'].validate(props.formRef.current.getValues("myId"), { context: { other: 4 } });
```

props.formRef.current.getValues("myId") is actually mapped to a textbox on the UI and as soon as I enter 123456789 and invoke the validation, I get an error saying;
this must be a `object` type, but the final value was: `null` (cast from the value `"123456789"`).

Not sure why it is saying the final value is: `null`

### Update

I have a server API call in my main component and based on that API response, I want to display the server error message via Yup's context.createError...So I want to pass isMyIdServiceError and MyIdServiceErrorMsg and display the error message in MyIdServiceErrorMsg, if isMyIdServiceError is true.

I am trying the below, but it does not work:

```
'myId': yup
    .string()
    .nullable()
    .required()
    .when(
        ['$isMyIdServiceError', '$MyIdServiceErrorMsg'],
        ([isMyIdServiceError, MyIdServiceErrorMsg], schema) => {
            if (isMyIdServiceError === true) {
                context.createError({
                    message: MyIdServiceErrorMsg
                });
            }
        }
    ),
```

Trying with test also throws ValidatonError in the console

```
'myId': yup
        .string()
        .nullable()
        .required()
        .test(
            'api-error',
            '${$MyIdServiceErrorMsg}',
            async function(value, ctx) {
                const {
                    ismyIdServiceError,
                    myIdServiceErrorMsg
                } = this.options.context;
                if (ismyIdServiceError) {
                    return ctx.createError({ path: 'myId', message: myIdServiceErrorMsg });
                }
                return true;
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing is because mySchema['add-record'] is expecting an object, but you're passing a string value directly.

In your schema definition, you've defined mySchema['add-record'] as an object with a property of 'myId', so when you call validate, it expects you to pass in an object with the same structure.

You should use the getValues() method without argument to get the entire form values as an object, then validate that object with your schema.

try this :

```
const formValues = props.formRef.current.getValues();
try {
   await mySchema['add-record'].validate(formValues, { context: { other: 
4 } });
  console.log('Validation passed!');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Validation failed with error:', error);
}
```

Comment: Hey...Thanks a lot...This works perfectly...I had one last related question...Basically, I have a server API call and based on that response, I want to display the server error message via Yup's context.createError

Comment: I have added details in the original question (under UPDATED)...It would be really helpful if you can help me with that before we close out.

Comment: Why are there multiple answers?

Answer (score 1):

try this for the error :

```
'myId': yup
.string()
.nullable()
.required()
.test(
    'api-error',
    '${$MyIdServiceErrorMsg}',
    function (value) {
        const { isMyIdServiceError, MyIdServiceErrorMsg } = this.options.context;
        if (isMyIdServiceError) {
            return this.createError({ message: MyIdServiceErrorMsg });
        }
        return true;
    }
)
```

Then, when calling validate(), you'll need to pass in the context like this:

```
const formValues = { myId: props.formRef.current.getValues("myId") };
const context = { isMyIdServiceError: /* your value */, MyIdServiceErrorMsg: /* your value */ };

try {
  await mySchema['add-record'].validate(formValues, { context });
  console.log('Validation passed!');
} catch (error) {
  console.error('Validation failed with error:', error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again...Just tried out...It goes inside the test function, but i see the JS error

Comment: Uncaught (in promise) ValidationError: Test Error Message
    at Object.createError (createValidation.js?f6e7:42:1)
    at Object.eval (ValidatonSchemaUtil.js?65ad:28:37)

Comment: This is after the line this.createError({ message: MyIdServiceErrorMsg }); gets executed

Comment: Clicking on the error in console takes me to this line in Yup's createValidation.js
      const error = new ValidationError(ValidationError.formatError(overrides.message || message, nextParams), value, nextParams.path, overrides.type || name);

Comment: can  you please replace the createError line with this :"return this.createError({ path: 'myId', message: MyIdServiceErrorMsg });"

Comment: can  you please replace the createError line with this :

Comment: Thanks...still throwing error in the console...Test Error Message
ValidationError: Test Error Message
    at Object.createError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/yup/es/util/createValidation.js:50:21)

Comment: I assume I need to use context somehow... so something like context.createError({message: MyIdServiceErrorMsg}) should show me the error message on the UI next to my textbox...though I am not 100% sure about that

Comment: though...adding context (as UPDATED/shown in my original question) also throws the same ValidationError

Comment: Not sure if you have any other recommendation for me